# Proving a term is $\Theta(n^{r})$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

$c$,$r$, and $n$ are positive integers with $n$ large enough.

I need to prove that $cn^{r}\epsilon^{\frac{r^2}{4}}= \Theta(n^{r})$. This definition is equivalent to finding $C$ and $C'$ which are real and $k$ such that $Cn^{r} \leq c'n^{r}\epsilon^{\frac{r^2}{4}} \leq C'n^{r}$ for all $n > k$.

I'm confused with the epsilon term. What possible values can $C$ take?

Comment: $\epsilon$ is a constant aswell right?

Comment: No info about it. I think it represents something small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\epsilon$ term is constant just like $c$, since it doesn't doesn't depend on $n$. So what you have is just an expresson of the form $K n^r$ where $K=c \epsilon^{\frac{r^2}{4}}$, which is of course $\Theta(n^r)$.